# Javascript for loop ajax potential race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, race-condition

Here's a simple loop I'm running:

```
for (var key in TestApp.config.services) {
  if (TestApp.config.services[key].files != "") {
    var files = TestApp.config.services[key].files.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i <= files.length - 1; i++) {
      var file_url = files[i];
      console.log("About to download :" + file_url);
      $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(file_url) + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        console.log("Downloaded file: " + file_url);
        console.log(key);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

The problem is that the `key` value is always the same by the time the JSON request finishes. How can I avoid this race condition so that the right `key` value is used when the `$.getJSON` is finished?

Comment: I would suggest creating the things happening in the inner for loop as a separate function you can pass the variables to. You could accomplish the same using closure but it's not recommended to create functions in loops. here's some info about it http://tobyho.com/2011/11/02/callbacks-in-loops/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an [Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
for (var key in TestApp.config.services) {
  if (TestApp.config.services[key].files != "") {
    var files = TestApp.config.services[key].files.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i <= files.length - 1; i++) {
      var file_url = files[i];
      console.log("About to download :" + file_url);

      // IIFE
      (function(thiskey,this_file_url){
          $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(this_file_url) + '&callback=?', function(data) {
            console.log("Downloaded file: " + this_file_url);
            console.log(thiskey);
          });
      })(key,file_url);


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i made a small edit to this, realising your callback not only needs `key`, but also `file_url`. You can see how you can pass as much scope as you need into an IIFE in this way

Answer (score -1):

One simple solution is to simply send the key with the request.  I prefer to write it in {} notation.

Let me give you the basis to an answer to your question; I will disregard the part with the files, to emphasize where to look at.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var items = ['Hello', 'World', 'foo', 'bar'];
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log("About to download :" + items[i] + '" - key: ' + i);
    $.getJSON( "ajax.php", 
      {
        url: items[i],
        key: i
      },
      function(data) {
        var key = data.key;
        console.log("Downloaded file: " + data.url + '" - key: ' + key);
      }
    );
  }
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('url'=>$_GET['url'], 'key'=>$_GET['key']));
?>
```